# How to compare dates in SharePoint List "A" to another Date in List "B"

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, calculated-column

So, I would like to Compare if any of my Dates from List "A" is between my StartDate and EndDate from List "B". I am new to sharepoint and any Article can show step by step would be greatly appreciated.

LIST "A"

| Holiday | Dates |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 05/12/2021 |
| 2 | 07/04/2021 |

LIST "B"

| STARTDATE | Dates | YES/NO (CALCULATED FIELD) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/01/2021 | 05/18/2021 | YES |
| 06/01/2021 | 07/03/2021 | NO |

need a calculated field like below:

```
YES/NO (CALCULATED FIELD)=  IF LISTA.DATES BETWEEN LISTB.DATE THEN YES ELSE NO
```

OR

***Hardcoding those days?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookup column (and its additional fields) cannot be referred in the Calculated column formula, if that is what you plan to do.

There are a few workarounds to achieve this requirement, for example:

1. Build a SharePoint 2013 workflow / Microsoft Flow to retrieve the corresponding value from *List A* and then fill it in another column in *List B*, so that it can be used in the calculated column formula.
2. Use workflow / flow to do the comparison and update the *YES/NO* field directly (without using calculated column and formula). It should be a Text or Yes/No column in this scenario.

You can see the reference here for a tutorial on using SharePoint 2013 workflow: [Using Lookup Field in Calculated Column SharePoint.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/lookup-field-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

And the calculated column formula should be:

```
IF(AND([<Ref.>]<=[ENDDATE],[<Ref.>]>=[STARTDATE]),"YES","NO")
```

Reference: [IF function.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-0a4ad187-dba3-48ae-abe9-bbe3aa6aebca)

Comment: I used your suggestion and hardcoded my calculated column. Thanks!